# Drawing a figure by clicking on a button using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to draw a circle on the screen by clicking on a button.

This is supposed to be expanded to draw some of them in specific places but for now I only need one.

JS code (Issue is in where it's written $scope.draw=function(ncircs) ... )

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);


app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.graph = {'width': 1000, 'height': 1000};

    $scope.circles = [

        JSON.parse("{\"x\": 85, \"y\": 20, \"r\":15}"),

        {"x": 20, "y": 60, "r":20},

        {"x": 18, "y": 10, "r":40}
    ];

        $scope.draw=function(val)
        {
            $scope.circles.push(JSON.parse('{\"x\":'+val+', "y": 220, "r":30}'));
        };

    $scope.rectangles = [

        /*    {'x':220,  'y':220,  'width' : 300, 'height' : 100},
        {'x':520,  'y':220,  'width' : 300, 'height' : 100}
        */
    ];

}
);

angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('body'), ["app"]);
```

HTML code:

```
<div id="body">
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <label>Num questões:</label>
    <input Id="NumQuest" class="span3" style="margin: 0pt auto;" type="text" placeholder="Num questões..." data-provide="typeahead" data-items="1"
           />

    <p><button ng-click="draw(NumQuest)">Draw</button></p>


    <svg ng-attr-height="{{graph.height}}" ng-attr-width="{{graph.width}}">

    <circle ng-repeat="circle in circles"

            ng-attr-cx="{{circle.x}}"

            ng-attr-cy="{{circle.y}}"

            ng-attr-r="{{circle.r}}">
    </circle>

     <rect ng-repeat="rect in rectangles"

           ng-attr-x="{{rect.x}}"

           ng-attr-y="{{rect.y}}"

           ng-attr-width="{{rect.width}}"

           ng-attr-height="{{rect.height}}">

     </rect>

     </svg>
 </div>
    </div>
```

My issue is that when I click on the draw button using the Id of the input button as parameter nothing works... I've tried everything... like $NumQuest, NumQuest.value, etc, etc...

Any help would be really valuable...

Bruno

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For someone who has the same issue as me, here's the fix:

The idea is that you use the value on the side of JS by getting the element by ID like this:

```
$scope.draw=function(val)
        {
            val = document.getElementById("NumQuest").value;
            $scope.circles.push(JSON.parse('{\"x\":'+val+', "y": 220, "r":30}'));
        };
```

Then everything else will work as expected if you simply use:

Draw

on the HTML side!! Simple and clean!